# .htaccess - Clean URLs prevent 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess file (which I got from other answers on here and on the web):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./$1.php
```

However, it seems that if the user manually enters an address that doesn't exist, it return a 500 Internal Server error. Any way I can prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: Check your servers's `error.log` to see what the error is? Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
```

because `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` checks for path info and other possible matches for scripts. This circumvents adding a `.php` to the end of the URI.